# jQuery requirements on a web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2008, deployment, webserver

I work for a big company and we have different environments like many others i guess : unit, system & production. We recently developed a website in ASP.NET using Entity FrameWork and generic jQuery plugins like Kinetics, jUnit, jQuery-UI, etc. The project is a Web Application in VS2008.

The website is running without any problem locally on the dev's computer. We migrated it into the unit system, some of the jQuery wasn't working. We then migrated into the System environemment to see if we were running into the same problems and 50% of the errors are gone. For sure, we don't want to migrate into production without having a stable unit\system env.

My question is, is there any specific stuff we need installed on our servers to make sure it runs perfectly like on the devs computer ? Any IIS settings or package we need installed ? Is it a problem with the webconfig ?  At this point, we need any inputs we need to fix this and get the site running as soon as possible.

Thanks everyone and i'll be online all day to respond promptly.

**EDIT**:
Here's a prime example of a code working in DEV\Syst but not in UNIT system. I have multiple cases like that.
Adding code from one of the failing webmethods (from Tommy's comment):

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function getRessourcesList() As String 
    Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
    Dim listOfRessources = (From ress In GetALLRessources() 
                            Select New With {
                                .label = ("(" & ress.NO_EMPLY & ") " & ress.PR & " " & ress.NM_FAML).Replace("""", "\"""), 
                                .id = ress.NO_EMPLY
                            }).ToList 
    Dim response As String = serializer.Serialize(listOfRessources) 
    Return response 
End Function
```

Comment: Check things like relative paths for ajax calls (or script includes for that matter). If the files aren't being retrieved (404s) because the script include is `/project/js/jquery.js` instead of `/js/jquery.js` that's going to be the first step in fixing this.

Comment: Some of the path are in the ./js/query.js form others in the the js/jquery.js form. Should I make them all in the /js/jquery.js format ?

Comment: Consistency is always good for future maintenance...make intentions clear. I would say make them consistent, though the two examples you gave happen to mean the same thing

Comment: Here's a classic example of a problem we have in UNIT env but not in system and local :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined   And the related error : if ($("#" + a + TableWeekTag)
        .css("width")
        .replace("px", "") < 1255) {
        $("#" + a + "SmallScrollDiv")
            .width(c)
    }    Why don't we have this error in the system and local env. and we do in unit ? I'm scratching my head big time with this type of cross platforms errors.

Comment: I'm going to guess that either the variables `a` or `TableWeekTag` are undefined. __OR__ I think you can set `ClientIDMode` in web.config...if that is set differently between dev and prod, nothing will ever work right if you're using `ASP` controls...which mangle html id's

Comment: Also it'd be really nice if you used proper formatting. Reading code in comments gives me (and others) a headache and doesn't do much for us wanting to help.... http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a front-end framework, nothing to do with the server. As long as your server is serving the files correctly (ie. not modifying them in any way), everything should work identically.

Comment: What do you think is wrong then ? Why was there a difference between the unit server and the system ?

Comment: What else you need more ? I'm available for you, we need to fix this.

Comment: Here's one we have when we want to load a list of users dynamically with an autocomplete: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: So it's a server problem then, not a jQuery problem.

Comment: Any ideas where I can look for ? More infos about the error:POST http://XXXXXX/getRessourcesList 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery-1.7.1.js:3Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: undefined

Comment: Your server log would be a good place to start, to see why it's generating 500 errors.

Comment: Here's the code in the getRessourcesList function in error : 
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function getRessourcesList() As String
        Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim listOfRessources = (From ress In GetALLRessources() Select New With {.label = ("(" & ress.NO_EMPLY & ") " & ress.PR & " " & ress.NM_FAML).Replace("""", "\"""), .id = ress.NO_EMPLY}).ToList

        Dim response As String = serializer.Serialize(listOfRessources)
        Return response
    End Function

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a client-side library and all the code you write which utilises the library runs on the client (in a standard setup, all else being equal - I'm not covering getting jQuery to run *on* the server for whatever reason).

No, jQuery has no server dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, jQuery is a client side library only.

However, is there a possibility that your app is deployed to a different path (port number, root folder, etc.) that may be causing a difference for relative paths in any ajax commands?